# Remove unecessary gradle imports

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

During the development of my app I used to import any support library i might use, now my code is more mature and ready for production and i'm trying to remove unecessary imports. is there an easy way to know which of the support library apis i'm really using?

I tried to comment one by one and see what makes the code doesn't compile, but there are some apis that aren't used explicit, like `vectordrawable:vectordrawable` that is supposed to be used internally by android

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Removing them 1 by 1 and seeing if it compiles is the way.  I'm not sure what you means by used internally, the other libraries you use should be self contained and import anything they need themselves.  (The other answer is not to import anything you aren't using, it will just slow down your compiles.  In the  end you're hurting yourself with that)

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of dependencies and details about each dependency using following commands.

```
gradlew -q app:dependencies

gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --configuration FLAVORNAMEReleaseCompileClasspath --dependency dependencyNAME

gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --configuration RanjanReleaseCompileClasspath --dependency com.google.android.libraries.tv:companionlibrary
```